# StringBuilder related issue

Tags: android

i have following code in which, i am fetching the data from the sqlite database. I am able to get all the values well whenever the data is upgraded but cant able to upgrade the values stored into a StringBuilder.So whenever the data is upgraded StringBuilder show the first data of the data base.

```
 private void showData(Cursor cursor) {

StringBuilder stbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
         start_time = cursor.getString(1);
         end_time = cursor.getString(2);
         duration_time = cursor.getString(3);
         phone_option = cursor.getString(4);
         phone_mode = cursor.getString(5);
         stbuilder.append(start_time+" "+end_time+" "+duration_time+" "+phone_option+" "+phone_mode);
        Log.i("STARTtttDB", ""+start_time);
    Log.i("enddddDB", ""+end_time);
    Log.i("duratonnn", ""+duration_time);
    Log.i("OpTIONnnnn",""+phone_option);
    Log.i("M O D E ",""+phone_mode);
    String data=stbuilder.toString();
    Log.i("Data OUtput",data);
```

}

Comment: Do you mean 'update' instead of 'upgrade'? Otherwise the question doesn't make sense to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **create a new StringBuilder** for each iteration, or reset it using:

`stBuilder.setLength(0)`.

Also, instead of using string concatenation (`+`) inside of StringBuilder.append(), **you should probably have a series of appends**:

```
stBuilder.append(start_time);
stBuilder.append(" ");
stBuilder.append(end_time);
...
```

Also note that you can **safely forgo the use of StringBuilder** altogether as the compiler optimizes string concatenation using StringBuilder anyway. Here is a [performance study](http://www.venishjoe.net/2009/11/java-string-concatenation-and.html) I found.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have another issue as well. Hope u have answer for it too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the StringBuilder with a call to setLength(0);

```
while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
    stBuilder.setLength(0);
    .....
}
```